# How to install Downloaded Postman Application in Centos7?

Tags: centos, software-installation, application

I have downloaded Postman from **https://www.postman.com/downloads/**  How to install in Centos 7.

Comment: Did you read the instructions?

Comment: @NasirRiley My workout => https://justpaste.it/2jk0o

Comment: @NasirRiley Tutorial link => https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-postman-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: Did you try that one? There is also this to install the version that you downloaded: https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/launching-postman/installation-and-updates/

Comment: I just extracted my postman application in RootFolder/Myfolder/postman/

Comment: To install manually, download and unzip the app, for example into the opt directory. You will need sudo privileges.   ==== I am extracted to root_folder/myfolder/postman/Postman inside that have 2 files app and installer